# Hibernate + JPA + SQL Server 2008 R2 (connection object issue)

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jpa

i am building a webservice that will be deployed in Apache Tomcat V7.
the DataBase Layer is under the JPA, Hibernate..however the issue here is randomely i get an error that cause the whole system to stop:

> WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] **SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01**
>   
> ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] **I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error** 
>   
> WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] **SQL Error: 0, SQLState: HY010** 
>   
> ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] **Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.** 
>   Blockquote

My Persistence.xml configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.12.12:1433/DB_STORE" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="s3cr3tp@ssw0rd" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

any suggestion help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try as below : In my application it is work well.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<server-address>:<port>;databaseName=<db-name>;selectMethod=cursor"/>
```

I use the following jar files-

```
msbase.jar
mssqlserver.jar
msutil.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
```